# react native Warning is prop-types?

Tags: react-native

Warning: Failed prop type: Label: prop type `style` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but received `undefined`.

Comment: Can you add more context, please? Can you also display the code, please?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the deprecate package: `react-native-material-textfield`. You should replace it with: [rn-material-ui-textfield](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-material-ui-textfield) which is a fork compatible with the latest versions of React Native.